# In R: return a data frame from apply to iteratively construct data.frame

Tags: r

An example explains best what I need to do:

```
# dd is a list and has some vars
dd = list()
dd$var = "some data is in here"

# now I want to add a sub data frame $new
dd$new = apply(as.array(seq(1,5)), 1, function(x){

  return( data.frame(
    a = x,
    b = x * 2
  ))

})

str(dd)

# desired structure #######################

#List of 2
# $ var: chr "some data is in here"
# $ new:List of 2
#  ..$ a: num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#  ..$ b: num [1:5] 2 4 6 8 10

#### Note: this is NOT what str(dd) actually gives, but what I want dd to look like!
```

How can I achieve this?

## EDIT

based on the answer marked as correct I could solve it:

```
# dd is a list and has some vars
dd = list()
dd$var = "some data is in here"

# now I want to add a sub data frame $new
ret = apply(as.array(seq(1,5)), 1, function(x){

  return( data.frame(
    a = x,
    b = x * 2
  ))

})    

dd$new = as.list(do.call(rbind, ret))

str(dd)
#List of 2
# $ var: chr "some data is in here"
# $ new:List of 2
#  ..$ a: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#  ..$ b: num [1:5] 2 4 6 8 10
```

## Also

there is no reason at all to downvote my question. The problem is stated in the comments of the code. The code is a working minimal example. I stated the desired answer. If you don't bother to read the code, well, at least don't downvote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
res <- setNames(list(dd[[1]], as.list(do.call(rbind, dd$new))), names(dd))
```

Comment: That got me going... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This gives the same message as you provided.

```
dd = list()
dd$var = "some data is in here"

dd$new <- list(a = 1:5, b = (1:5)*2)
str(dd)
```

Comment: Sure. But the stuff in the apply FUN does something more complicated as shown in the minimal example.